# Access files and directories in a shared drive using php

Tags: php

i'm coding a web application that will be like a file explorer like 'windows file manager', when i give a path to a folder in the application, it will list all folders and files and i can manipulate them like (rename, delete, move, zip). the application works very well when i give it a path to a folder on my computer.

my problem is when I provide it with a path to a shared folder over a network, it doesn't work.
i usually access this shared folder by typing a link of the form:"\sharedrive00" in the search.
note that my computer is connected to a domain. i've made several searches but haven't found much to help me.

as the application works very well with a folder path on my computer, I tried replacing this path with the shared folder path. it's not working.

i try this code from the forum

```
<?php

$user = 'mickeymouse';
$password = 'helloworld';

exec('net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /user:"'.$user.'" "'.$password.'" /persistent:no');
$files = scandir('\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($files);

exec('net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /delete /yes');
```

but it's doesn't work also.

```
 here is my code   
 function listDir($folder = null)
{
$_SESSION['ROOT_ACTIVE'] = $_SESSION['ROOT_PATH'] . '//' .$folder??'';

    $directories = glob($_SESSION['ROOT_ACTIVE'] . '*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $dir = str_replace($_SESSION['ROOT_ACTIVE'], ' ', $directories);
    $result = [];
    if ($dir == null) 
{
    echo 'empty directory';
} else 
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dir); $i++) 
{
   $var = $dir[$i];
   $result[] = '
  <a class="nav-link collapsed link" back="" id="link" href="pages/page1.php?id=' . urldecode(str_replace(' ', '', $var)) . '&link=' . urlencode(str_replace(' ', '', $_SESSION['ROOT_ACTIVE'])) . urldecode(str_replace(' ', '', $var)) . '">
 <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></div>'. $var . '';
}
}
  return $result;
}
```

when i pass the path link to this function, it does not retrieve the directories.

Comment: What does not work? Any errors received?